# How do I create a workbook using openpyxl?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

i doing some school work with the openpyxl module. I tried to create a basic workbook object and ran into a problem i am still not able to actually sort out. I have taken a look at the error questions asked before, it seems everyone else is using the same method and it has worked but i dont know why it is just not working for me. I went through the openpyxl documentation and is still porblem unsolved. This is what i did.

> > > from openpyxl import workbook
> > >       wb = workbook()
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >       File "", line 1, in 
> > >       TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

and when i use this:

```
>>> wb = workbook
```

then i get type:

```
>>> type(wb)
 <class 'module'>
```

but if i try to get the ws objectlike this:

```
>>> ws = wb.active
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 AttributeError: module 'openpyxl.workbook' has no attribute 'active'
```

so because this have failed i tried another alternative:

```
>>> ws = wb.get_sheet_by_names
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 AttributeError: module 'openpyxl.workbook' has no attribute'get_sheet_by_names'
```

so i tried to do a version chec with this small code:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import workbook

if openpyxl.__version__ == '2.4.1':
    print('Openpyxl is ' + str(openpyxl.__version__) + ' then its up to     date')
if openpyxl.__version__ != '2.4.1':
    print('Openpyxl is ' + str(openpyxl.__version__))
```

so it seems all the codes i using seems to be the right codes but however will returni cant bury under my depths. I dont actually know whats going on. Would anyone kindly helpout? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the *module* `workbook` like the *class* `Workbook`. 
`Workbook` is a class within the `openpyxl.workbook`  module and needs to be imported accordingly. Noticed the difference in the capitalization of `Workbook` and `workbook`. Python is case-sensitive, meaning `Workbook` and `workbook` are two difference instances

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook, workbook

print(type(Workbook))
>>> <class 'type'>

print(type(workbook))
>>> <class 'module'>

wb = Workbook()
print(type(wb))
>>> <class 'openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook'>
```

Comment: yes i did import the class like this in the beginning: (>>>from openpyxl import workbook) but it will not yield anything.  Now i have tried your code and this is what i got : ('>>> import openpyxl
>>> from openpyxl.workbook import workbook
>>> wb = workbook()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable')

Comment: @Wondercricket....Sorry mait...actually you did solve my problem for me on your first attempt. I missed the 'Capitalized' word from your answer. Just realised i was instead doing all the the lowercases n that being the case it was not responding. |You know like the saying "A little bit of rest helps to open the mind "|...It is working now...My bad....Thnx for assistance gr8tly appreciate it. .....>>> from openpyxl import Workbook
>>> wb = Workbook()
>>> ws = wb.active
>>> ws.title
'Sheet'
>>> ws.title = 'Mombo Jombo'
>>> ws.title
'Mombo Jombo'
>>>

Answer (score 0):

Python's casesensitivity took the best of me. I was using lowercase instead of uppercase.